# How to set up a breakpoint to catch the USB device getting control?

Tags: debugging, gdb, usb, qnx

I need to understand how the code on a USB gets the control after plug-in to the QNX device. What I already done:

1. Save slogger output (using sloginfo) during plugging the USB

Through it I understand that devb-umass driver and then mme-update get the control. I got and disasm the mme-update. Find the string from sloginfo and code that prints it

2. I ran gdb, check memory on needed addresses (it's ok, just like in disasm) and set breakpoint on code and watchpoint on a string. Plan was to trace the code further till USB code
3. Eject and plug the USB again. No reaction

Could you please give some ideas why? May be you can thing of a better way to understand how code on the USB gets the control? Changing some byte to 0xCC on a USB doesn't seem the solution

Comment: How you invoke gdb ??? Put here the string.

Comment: Did you attach to `devb-umass` process??????